# Excel window partially cut off when maximized on one monitor

Tags: microsoft-excel, multiple-monitors

I have two 24" monitors.  When I open and maximize Excel on the lead monitor all is good.  When I open and maximize on the second monitor, the left edge goes off of the screen, partially obscuring the Excel icon and half of the row number column.  The screens are set to the same resolution.

Any suggestions as to how to fix this?

Comment: Version of Excel, Windows etc would be useful...

Answer (score 1):

This is a monitor configuration problem. The answer is going to be dependent on the monitor model you are using. You will want to adjust the 'Horizontal Position' (sometimes called 'H Pos' or 'H-Position') of the display. You may also want to adjust the 'Image Size' option if you have not already done so.

This fix can also be done using your video card but at a slight cost in performance. NVidia driver software has an option for 'Adjust desktop size and position' which can be used to fine tune this as well.